# Ideavim plugin for Intellij keymaps

Tags: vim, intellij-idea, pycharm, ideavim

I'm trying to get the Ideavim plugin to work correctly in Intellij IDEA and PyCharm, but the documentation is rather poor and I can't configure it properly.

For starters, the documentation tells me to choose the VIM keymap under Preferences/Keymap but there is no VIM keymap there before or after installing Ideavim.

Also, according to the documentation some plugins are suposed to be supported (altough the documentation doesn't say wich and only talks about vim-surreound), but even after putting the line in `~/.ideavimrc`:

```
set vim-surround
```

The vim-surround commands simply don't work.

Also, where are the actions/commands list that can be used in `~/.ideavimrc` to map some keybinding.

For instance, imagine I want to remap `<leader> f s` to save my file. Where do I find out the commands available so that I can put something like in `~/.ideavimrc`:

```
let mapleader = " "
nmap <LEADER>fs :SaveFile<CR>
```

Answer (score 8):

Vim-surround emulation is not released yet. You can download CI builds that include vim-surround support using a link at https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim.

In order to enable vim-surround, use:

```
set surround
```

You can list all the IDE commands available for mapping using `:actionlist`. See the documentation at the GitHub page.

**Update:** IdeaVim 0.46 supports vim-surround commands.

Comment: Thank you. The `:actionlist` command really helps a lot. But I still can't change the keymap to Vim. Don't know if that's because of that, but for instance in an iPython notebook inside PyCharm, the Vim commands don't work.

Comment: There is no separate Vim keymap any longer. Just enable the Vim emulation in the tools menu, it works with any keymap. For problems with IPython Notebook see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-1030

Comment: Browsed everything here https://teamcity.jetbrains.com/viewType.html?buildTypeId=IdeaVim_Build. Don't undestand how to download last version? Could someone explain?

Comment: @StalkAlex See https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim#get-an-early-access

Comment: 2016/7/8 The newest ideavim has support this function.